# Perform Iterative Operations on OUTEST or OUTSTAT variables in SAS?

Tags: sas, regression

In SAS, how can I assign a variable coming from either the OUTEST or OUTSTAT functions to be used in a **loop**?

For example, say I want to run some sort of iterative analysis until my mean (average) reaches a certain threshold. I know how to extract the mean using either OUTEST or OUTSTAT, but then how can I perform operations or blocks of code on it?

Thank you.

If you are interested in details, I am trying to perform backward selection of VIFs (to remove multicollinearity). Unfortunately, SAS doesn't seem to have a 'SELECTION=BACKWARD' feature for this...

EDIT: Updated with sample code:

```
%MACRO MULTICOLLINEARITY(TABLE_SUFFIX,YVAR,FIELDS,MAX_VIF);

/* PRELIMINARY PROC REG ON ALL FIELDS*/
PROC REG DATA=TABLE_&TABLE_SUFFIX. NOPRINT;
MODEL &YVAR = &FIELDS / VIF COLLIN NOINT;
ODS OUTPUT PARAMETERESTIMATES=PAREST1;
RUN;

/* RETAIN NON-NULL VIF FIELDS ONLY */
DATA NO_NULL_VIF;
SET PAREST1 (WHERE=(VarianceInflation <> .));
RUN;

/* CREATE VARIABLE LIST OF NON-NULL VIF FIELDS */
PROC SQL;
SELECT VARIABLE
INTO :NO_NULL_VIF_FIELDS SEPARATED BY ' '
FROM NO_NULL_VIF;
QUIT;

/* RE-RUN REGRESSION WITH NON-NULL VIF FIELDS ONLY */
PROC REG DATA=TABLE_&TABLE_SUFFIX. NOPRINT;
MODEL &YVAR = &NO_NULL_VIF_FIELDS / VIF COLLIN NOINT;
ODS OUTPUT PARAMETERESTIMATES=PAREST2;
RUN;

/* START ITERATION OF DROPPING THE HIGHEST VIF UNTIL THE CRITERIA IS MET */

???

%MEND;

%MULTICOLLINEARITY(, RESPONSE, &INPUT_FIELDS,???)
```

And by criteria I mean VIF_MAX < N where N is some threshold specified in the macro. For example, if we want to retain only fields with VIF less than 5, then it should drop the highest one, re-run the PROC REG, drop the highest, re-run, etc. etc. until the highest on is less than 5.

Comment: You should provide some code here, preferably using a SASHELP dataset or something you describe in the question, so we understand the context you're using.  What PROC is this in, for that matter?

Comment: If you're using PROC REG, it does have selection=B(ackward), according to the [9.2 documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect030.htm) at least.

Comment: Hi Joe. I will provide code shortly. It is indeed for PROC REG but the SELECTION=BACKWARD only applies to things like PVALUE, etc. not to VIF. Please do correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Joe. Updated code and notes there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off - I'd verify that you can't do this using PROC MODEL.  I'm not a regression guy so I don't know for sure.  Might be worth posting on a more stat-focused site; CV isn't really appropriate since they're not generally trying to answer software questions, but maybe communities.sas.com .  I would find it surprising if this wasn't directly possible in PROC MODEL and/or in one of the more complicated procs.

Second, the way I'd approach this is to write a recursive macro. Take out the first part (the non-null VIF fields) and either move that to an outer macro that just runs once, or make it an expectation of the programmer to do on his/her own (unless this is not feasible, and/or can change with iterations - not something I'm knowledgeable of).  Then do something like this:

```
%MACRO MULTICOLLINEARITY(TABLE_SUFFIX,YVAR,FIELDS,MAX_VIF);
    ods _all_ close;
    %put Running with &fields;  *note which fields currently running;
                                *also may want to include a run # counter as parameter;
    PROC REG DATA=TABLE_&TABLE_SUFFIX.;
      MODEL &YVAR = &FIELDS / VIF COLLIN NOINT;
      ODS OUTPUT PARAMETERESTIMATES=PAREST2;
    RUN;
    quit;
    *Data step to analyse PAREST2 and see if any of the fields can be dropped;

    proc sort data=parest2;
      by descending varianceinflation;
    run;

    data _null_;
      set parest2(obs=1);
      if varianceinflation > &max_vif then do;
        fields_run = tranwrd("&fields",trim(variable),' ');
        if not missing(fields_run) then do;
            call_string = cats('%multicollinearity(',"&table_suffix.,&yvar.,",fields_run,",&max_vif.)");
            call execute(call_string);
        end;
      end;
      else do;
        put "Stopped with Max VIF:" variable "=" varianceinflation;
    run;

    ods preferences;
%MEND MULTICOLLINEARITY;
```

Then you call it once with the full field list, and it calls itself in the `CALL EXECUTE` if there is still a parameter left.  An incremented # of runs may be helpful (both to see how many times it ran in your log, and to be able to make sure that you don't end up in an infinite loop if you make a mistake with the fields variable deletion.)

I would run this with `OPTION NONOTES NOSOURCE;` and none of the symbogen/mprint stuff on, so you can just get the %put/put statements in your log.

Comment: Thanks a million, Joe. I'm working with this and it has made my life a whole lot easier. I'll definitely consult with a more stats-focused community going forward. Till then, you have been super-helpful!